# Founders of undetermined forms

Tags: mathematicians, calculus, scientists

Who are the people actually 1st to mention about undetermined forms like 0^∞ or 0/0 or ∞/∞ etc .
In which books these forms are mentioned and if the people were not known specifically , mention the region where these forms are mentioned in that region's scientific works.